# Estoy ingresando un texto en el value y Selenium IDE no me escribe el valor completo al ejecutar la prueba

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-ide

> En el punto 28 y 30, al correr la prueba no me respeta el value completo asignado
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizá no tengas que poner espacios para el número de la tarjeta.

Comment: solo en caso de que fuera el sitio de unodostres https://github.com/javatlacati/unodostresproficiencyexercise